# Table with low selectivity ratio

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have one table now with million rows..

```
Table-1

Name, Age, Sex, Dept
Tom   25   M    Finance
.
.
.
```

Now, The "Finance" is reptitive...Currently, there is only one dept "Finance"..

Is it good to normalize the data to a different table..

```
Finance Table

Id Name
1  Finance
```

and refer Finance-id in the Table-1

Comment: It would make a lot more sense to provide your actual table definition showing actual data types and constraints (complete `CREATE TABLE` script or what you get with `\d tbl` in psql). That bare minimum of abstracted information is  not very useful. And *always* your version of Postgres. Also "Is it good?" is not a good question. Describe what your situation is (how many users, access patterns etc.) and what you hope to achieve.

Comment: So your one and only finance department consists of a million employees. Interesting. My suggestion is that you not store time-varying data, like age. Instead, store the constant value, birth date, and calculate the age in the query. That way, your data will not be in constant need of updating.

Answer (score 1):

In general, you have a heavily de-normalized table, and a bit of normalizing would do some good.

Since you appear to be new to database design, I understand you may not really be aware of what normalization is, so we'll keep it simple and say that for a normalized structure, you want each piece of data to exist in one place only, so that it is not copied repeatedly in many locations.

Of course, you'll find that the [**Wikipedia page on database normalization**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) is a good start.

**Let's look at your specific case:**

**1)** You have the individual's name directly in the row data.  This is fine if a person is referenced once and only once, but what if the a person is part of the data for other tables?  Do you want to copy their name every time?  What if they get married or for some other reason they change their name?  Now you'll have to track down every instance of their name.  What if two people have the exact same name?  How do you discern between them?

In general having a table with unique person ids as

```
CREATE TABLE people(
  person_id int,
  first_name text,
  last_name text,
  etc...
);
```

would be a good idea.  Then simply place the `person_id` into any other relevant table.

**2)** So, putting someone's `age` into a table is a pretty bad idea.  Doing it this way, every day you need to go through the table, see if it is someone's birthday, and update any corresponding entry.

Why bother with that when you can simply store their birthday once, and all relevant information is encapsulated in that one, never changing piece of data? Futher, since it is definitively attached to the person, add their birthdate as a column entry in the previously mentioned `people` table.

**3)** You can already see where I'm going with this: this data also belongs in the `people` table.

**4)** Now we're on to your original question.  Yes, I believe you should have a separate table which lists the different departments.

```
CREATE TABLE depts(
  dept_id int,
  name text,
  other_info text,
  etc...
);
```

Lastly, joining people to departments can simply be done with a table having two integer columns:

```
CREATE TABLE employees(
  person_id int,
  dept_id int
);
```

Hope this helps!

**P.S.**: I've made it sound like normalization is *always* the right answer. In actuality, it is often the right answer, but not always.  They key is, learn to normalize an why you should, so that you can then make key decisions about why you might choose to intentionally de-normalize your data.

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation..I don't expect the DEPT table to grow at all..It will have only one row anytime...Still do you think I need separate table...

Comment: I agree with the age column..Thats for more an generic example..Im more concerned about DEPT_ID as it will have just one value

Comment: If you will only ever have a single department (`Finance`), then why bother to include the data as a column at all?  Simply name the table `finance_employees` and leave out that column all together, since it is implied by the table.